# Why Integers in csv file read as strings into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

In the following csv file, some columns contain data with different datatypes, i.e. some rows are integers and some rows are strings.

```
"ip_v", "ittl", "olen", "mss",  "OS_type"
 "*",    64,       0,     "*",   "Windows"
  4,     64,       0,    1430,   "Linux"
 "*",   "64-",     0,    1460,   "MAC-OS"
```

I read the csv file into pandas dataframe
`df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")`
And iterate through each row in a for loop and check the type of each value to proceed further.
But, though the values types are different in csv file, in python all values are read as `strings`. For example, when I check the type for `"ittl"` column values in each row, they all read as string but I was expecting `row 0 and 1 to be int` and `row 2 to be str`.
Why am I facing this problem, what is going on?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['ittl'], type(row['ittl']))

Output:
64    <class 'str'>
64    <class 'str'>
64-   <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know but if you want to make your column as an int type you can make this:

`df['ittl'] = df['ittl'].astype(int)`

Comment: But changing the type of entire column in which some values ("64-") cannot be typecasted to integers. And that is not what I want. Even if I try I get this error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '64-'`

Comment: I want their type to be as same as in the CSV file. I am expecting an integer value from csv without double-quot `(64)` should be read as integer, and the same integer value with double-quot `("64")` should be read as string. Am I wrong?